# XElement(s) for Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following "exception hierarchy"

```
        Exception one = new ArithmeticException("Numbers are yucky");
        Exception two = new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Files stinks", one);
        Exception three = new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Arguments hurt", two);
```

I'm trying to create the below xml..here is my existing code (and I understand why it doesn't give me the expected results)

```
        XDocument returnDoc = new XDocument();
        XElement root = new XElement("root");

        if (null != three)
        {

            XElement exceptionElement = new XElement("Exception");

            Exception exc = ex;
            while (null != exc)
            {

                exceptionElement.Add(new XElement("Message", exc.Message));

                exc = exc.InnerException;
            }

            root.Add(exceptionElement);

        }


        returnDoc.Add(root);
```

I get this xml:

```
<root>
    <Exception>
        <Message>Arguments hurt</Message>
        <Message>Files stinks</Message>
        <Message>Numbers are yucky</Message>
    </Exception>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get this Xml...

```
<root>
    <Exception>
        <Message>Arguments hurt</Message>
        <Exception>
            <Message>Files stinks</Message>
            <Exception>
                <Message>Numbers are yucky</Message>
            </Exception>
        </Exception>
    </Exception>
</root>
```

The number of "nested" exceptions is not known....it could be 1 to N.

I can't get a "recursive XElement" to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (null != three)
{

    XElement currentElement = root;
    Exception exc = three;
    while (null != exc)
    {
        XElement exceptionElement = new XElement("Exception");
        exceptionElement.Add(new XElement("Message", exc.Message));
        exc = exc.InnerException;

        currentElement.Add(exceptionElement);
        currentElement = exceptionElement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I was so close.  I missed the "XElement currentElement = root;" part.   Thanks!